# Delay in logging Drupal user through Services

Tags: users, services

I have two Drupal7 sites. I am using a service that allows a registered user to login using session authentication.

On the site that performs the call to my remote service I measured the time when I enter the login function and after I got my session id response. It is 6 seconds apart.

When I use the browser to login it works as normal, no delays.
Both Drupal7 instances are running on localhost.

I need some pointers as to where to look in order to reduce this latency.

```
watchdog("LOG", "Login function hit at " . date(DATE_RFC2822));
$resource = 'access/';

$this->options = array(
  'headers' => array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => json_encode(array(
    'username' => $this->username,
    'password' => $this->password,
  )),
);

$response = drupal_http_request($this->base_url . $resource . 'user/login', $this->options);
$data = json_decode($response->data);

// Check response code
if ($response->code == 200 && $data != null) {
  $this->options['headers']['Cookie'] = $data->session_name . '=' . $data->sessid;
  watchdog("LOG", "Connected to remote at " . date(DATE_RFC2822));
}
```

I wrote a basic php login function to run it from outside a Drupal install and the time to login is 5 seconds. Measured the web login and it's instant. I also switched from Services Resource API 1.0 to 1.1 with no improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks unrelated to drupal itself but it's more likely to be a glitch / misconfiguration in the web server/LAMPP settings or a DNS lookup issue.

Can you please let us know more about your LAMPP stack and OS?

Also consider trying the following:

1. Setting the ServerName property in httpd.conf ( `ServerName
     127.0.0.1:80` )
2. If the above doesn't work, in your httpd.conf be sure to set the setting `HostnameLookups Off`
3. Enable slow query log in MySQL.
4. Have a look at this post https://serverfault.com/questions/66347/why-is-the-response-on-localhost-so-slow

Comment: I'm on Mac OSx 10.9.1, running apache5, PHP 5.4. I'll follow the above and see if it improves.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but I have virtual hosts in Apache. The web server runs fast when I use it from the browser.

Comment: I think using virtual hosts was the problem. I am now logging through the http://localhost/website path and it works way faster than having a http://website.local hostname. I'd like to know if there is any way I can speed it up.

Comment: Have you followed the above ? Those are good practice rules of thumb.

Comment: If disabling virtual hosts helped that only confirms that there was a DNS issue causing it.